# How does the fed pump the stock market

Tags: stock-market, money, federal-reserve

I've been hearing a lot about the fed "pumping the stock market" with trillions of dollars to maintain prices. I know the fed isn't allowed to actually buy stocks so how is this money being spent, if not on stocks, to "pump the market"? Who is receiving this money? How do those entities receive the money and it effect their stock?

Comment: This question is only going to have opinion-based answers. If an actual mechanism for “pumping the stock market” existed, it could be discussed.